# Georeferenced points not connected

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

After georeferencing the Google Earth image with 4 points, it appears as shown in the image below. And sometimes it extends the point connected lines outside of the image. I'd like to frame it with the four points and then use it as a map in QGIS to add features as same as the 2nd attached photo?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The lines are effectively error bars showing how far off the location you clicked as a georeference point the image still is. Have you tried using more georeferencing points? Four is probably a minimum and you'll probably get a better result if you use more.

Comment: Did you know you can add Google layers to your map using the quickmapservices plugin?